# Laravel get Property of Eloquent builder instance

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am having trouble to access the property values of the vendorname or vendordescription. This call function `$vendor->vendorname;` would return an error
`Property [vendorname] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance.`

How can I access the property value of the vendorname or vendordescription? Thank you

Model return object in the website

```
 Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder {#1330 ▼
  #query: Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder {#381 ▶}
  #model: App\Models\Vendor {#1349 ▼
    #fillable: array:2 [▶]
    #connection: "mysql"
    #table: "vendors"
    #primaryKey: "id"
    #keyType: "int"
    +incrementing: true
    #with: []
    #withCount: []
    +preventsLazyLoading: false
    #perPage: 15
    +exists: true
    +wasRecentlyCreated: false
    #attributes: array:5 [▼
      "id" => 2
      "created_at" => "2021-08-01 11:48:20"
      "updated_at" => "2021-08-01 11:48:20"
      "vendorname" => "cloyad"
      "vendordescription" => "cloyad"
    ]
    #original: array:5 [▶]
    #changes: []
    #casts: []
    #classCastCache: []
    #dates: []
    #dateFormat: null
    #appends: []
    #dispatchesEvents: []
    #observables: []
    #relations: array:1 [▶]
    #touches: []
    +timestamps: true
    #hidden: []
    #visible: []
    #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  }
  #eagerLoad: []
  #localMacros: []
  #onDelete: null
  #passthru: array:19 [▶]
  #scopes: []
  #removedScopes: []
}
```

Controller function in App/Http/Controllers

```
    public function index(User $user, Request $request){
        //Retrieve the favroutie listings from user
        $fav = User::with('posts')->get()->where('id', $user->id);
        //dd($fav);
        $favArray = [];
        foreach($fav as $t){
            foreach($t->posts as $p){
                $collection = collect();
                $collection->push($p);
                $vendor = Vendor::with('posts')->first()->where('post_id', $p->id);
                dd($vendor->vendorname);
                array_unshift($favArray, $p);
            }
        }
    }
```

Solution to get from both Models with the pivot table

```
public function index(User $user, Request $request){
        //Retrieve the favroutie listings from user
        $fav = User::with('posts')->get()->where('id', $user->id);
        //dd($fav);
        $favArray = [];
        foreach($fav as $t){
            foreach($t->posts as $p){
                $collection = collect();
                $collection->push($p);
                $vendor = Vendor::with('posts')->get();
                foreach($vendor as $v){
                    foreach($v->posts as $vv){
                        if($vv->id == $p->id){
                            $collection->push($v);
                        }
                    }
                }
                array_unshift($favArray, $collection);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add your php code in your question.

Comment: I already have added in the php code, thanks

Comment: `$vendor = Vendor::with('posts')->where('post_id', $p->id)->first();` you may try

Comment: thank you, but it doesn't work because the 'post_id' is from the pivot table. It required to get all the items before it and query it. I came up with a solution myself already and have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can query all of the required vendors before entering foreach loop, then search on the returned items in the memory.

```
foreach($fav as $t){
    $vendors = Vendor::with('posts')->whereIn('post_id', data_get($t->posts, '*.id', []))->get();
    foreach($t->posts as $p){
        $collection = collect();
        $collection->push($p);
        $vendor = $vendors->where('post_id', $p->id)->first();
        dd($vendor->vendorname);
        array_unshift($favArray, $p);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but I have already came up with a solution and edited my post. :) I tried to upvote but I can't due to my low reputation, sorry.